How to convert this Linq to lambda expression (Introducing the online converter)
Do you know any software or online web application or a tool in Visual Studio that can do this conversion?
And please someone help me, I can't convert this complex (to Linq Like This : From x in UserRoleid Select x ... Where ...)
        var Result = userRoleIds.Select(s => (s.UserId, actionFullNames.Select(actionFullName 
          => (actionFullName, permissions.Any(A => s.RoleIds.Contains(A.RoleId) && 
          A.ActionFullName.Equals(actionFullName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))))
         .ToArray())).ToArray();

For Example :
context.table.Where(a => a.FK.ID == b.Number).Sum(a => a.sumPrice)
=====To=This=====>
(from a in context.table where a.FK.ID == b.Number select a.sumPrice).Sum()


Assuming that userRoleIds is an IEnumerable of some kind, the use of .Select() is already a Linq call. So what needs to be converted to what (and why)? Please be more specific.

I'm not aware of any tool for this. Also, since you didn't give exactly models, I'm assuming you have these models
public class UserRole
{
    public int UserRoleId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int[] RoleIds { get; set; }
}

public class Permission
{
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string ActionFullName { get; set; }
}

Then your syntatic sugar will be like
var result = (from userRole in userRoles
              select new
              {
                  userRole.UserId,
                  SomeTuple = (from actionFullName in actionFullNames
                               select new
                               {
                                   ActionFullName = actionFullName,
                                   IsMatched = (from permission in permissions
                                              where userRole.RoleIds.Contains(permission.RoleId) &&
                                                    permission.ActionFullName.Equals(actionFullName,
                                                        StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                                              select permission).Any()
                               }).ToArray()
              }).ToArray();

This style doesn't support all the linq methods (e.g Any())

I don't believe that you even mentioned the members of the class correctly :)))) Thank You
